# Security token between domains for WCF service

Tags: security, wcf, cross-domain

I have a WCF service on machine *domain1\server1* that is accessible from a client on the machine *domain2\clientA* but not from machine *domain2\clientB*. From B I receive the error "the caller was not authenticated by the service (mscorlib, System.ServiceModel)".

The user account *domain2\username* is the same and this account has the same rights on the clients A and B; A and B are comparable machines.

The installation of the client software on A is via click-once deployment on Sharepoint succeeded on both clients A and B.

Has anybody an opinion on the cause of the difference?
What kind of configuration on *domain1\server1* could be involved?

Answer (score 0):

A net use connection existed between A and te server. I discoverd it because it stopped working when I changed the password. After adding a windows credential under user accounts credential manager it started to work.